# vba loop to add to string- Current code overwrites instead of adding to cell

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I am trying to add to cell however my code keeps overwriting itself.

**Example**:

In a row if there is a value from columns 5 to 11, I want the heading appended to a specific cell (last cell in column M).

If cells e2=Jan f2=Feb g2=Mar
and e3=100 f3=40 g3=0

I want to see in last row of M "State - Jan, Feb"

Currently the codes is ending in "State - Feb" because it seems to overite "Jan" instead of adding to it.

```
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim sDesc as string, sDesc2 As String
Dim wsEntry As Worksheet
Dim wsUp As Worksheet
Set wsEntry = Worksheets("Entries")
Set wsUp = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sRange As Range

For iRow = 6 To 7
    lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    sDesc = wsEntry.Range("M" & iRow).Value
    wsUp.Range("M" & lastrow + 1).Value = sDesc

    For iCol = 5 To 11
        If Cells(iRow, iCol) > "0" Then
            sEnt3 = wsEntry.Cells(5, iCol).Value
            sDesc2 = sDesc & sEnt3 & ", "
            wsUp.Range("M" & lastrow).Value = sDesc2
        End If
    Next iCol
```

Comment: Apart from the issue with the appending of strings (due to resetting `SDesc` every time through the `icol` loop), your code seems to be rewriting information on the `lastrow` row and/or `lastrow+1` row for each iteration of the `iRow` loop (because `lastrow` will be the same value each iteration).  It might be an idea to paste an image of your code into the question so that we can see what you are trying to achieve.  (Although that may not be an issue if there is other code, that updates column A, that hasn't been shown.)

Comment: Last row wont be the same for each iteration. This is part of a longer code where I have formulas in a table and then using that table to create journal entries. I realize I am resetting sDec everytime through the iCol but not sure how to fix that. I dont want it reset. I wan to add to it.  I can post the  entire code if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the string concatenation can be solved by not resetting the value of `SDesc2` every time through the `icol` loop, and then updating the cell only after the end of the loop:

```
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim sDesc as string, sDesc2 As String
Dim wsEntry As Worksheet
Dim wsUp As Worksheet
Set wsEntry = Worksheets("Entries")
Set wsUp = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sRange As Range

For iRow = 6 To 7
    'Qualify "Rows"
    lastrow = wsUp.Cells(wsUp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    sDesc = wsEntry.Range("M" & iRow).Value

    sDesc2 = ""
    For iCol = 5 To 11
        'Qualify "Cells" (I have assumed you were referring to wsEntry)
        If wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value > 0 Then  ' Test numeric values, not strings
            'Append comma only if something already present in the result
            If sDesc2 <> "" Then
                sDesc2 = sDesc2 & ", "
            End If
            sDesc2 = sDesc2 & wsEntry.Cells(5, iCol).Value
        End If
    Next iCol

    wsUp.Range("M" & lastrow + 1).Value = sDesc & sDesc2
```